# Android Best Practice - Communication between Activity and Fragments

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-fragments, communication

Hope you guys can clarify something for me.

I've been using Android for about 6 months now and I'm still confused about the best way to communicate between Activity and Fragments. I've already read the the info on the [android developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)).

### Fragment to Activity

Right now I know with 100% absolute certainty that an interface is the best way to communicate from Fragment to Activity. I.e. creating an interface in your Fragment and letting your Activity implement it. This way you can call the method from your interface inside your Fragment and have it handled by the Activity (which implements the interface).

### Activity to Fragment

Here's were I'm not sure. The android developer site says that in order to communicate with a Fragment you have to put your objects in a Bundle.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(SOME_IDENTIFIER, myInt);
```

Now I've been know to use a Singleton class every now and then when I have quite some functionality that I can separate. Say I have a Singleton called `PersistenceService` where I handle all of the persistence related stuff, e.g. saving something in the `SharedPreferences`. The `PersistenceService` will then hold methods like `putMyString(String key, String myString)` or `putSomeObject(String key, SomeObject someObj)`. This way a class doesn't have to handle persistence itself but can just call the `PersistenceService` to do it.

Now say I have to update something in my Fragment, a TextView or something.
This is what I do:

```
String myString = PersistenceService.getInstance(getActivity()).getMyString(someKey);
textView.setText(myString);
```

*I pass in a context (`getActivity()`) because I need it to get the `SharedPreferences`.*

Now my actual question is:

**Do I retrieve my data in the Activity and pass it to the desired Fragment through its Bundle? Or do I simply reference my Singleton right in my Fragment and access the data there directly.**

I'm not stuck or anything, but I'd like to know what you guys would recommend.
Any advice, remarks, info etc. is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question, and as the pragmatic thinking and learning book says, the answer to most questions in software is "It all depends!".

And it really does, it really all depends, there's no hard rule in software, "always" and "never" are very powerful words that shouldn't be used in software, so, saying always go for "Bundle" info or Never go for a Singleton is a little bit stupid specifically in software, so, instead of telling you exactly what to use, ask your self what would fit better in your needs taking on count things like, scalability, extensibility manageability, etc. For example:

If you go for Bundle, you give some flexibility to your fragment, you are creating some kind of independent component ready to work with whatever information you provide, on the other hand, if you know that you need that fragment only in that place, and the information you will pass is somehow complex(can't be passed using a bundle), why complicating so much? Just go for the Singleton if it does the job simple and clean.

I hope my point is well explained here, there's no hard rules for one way or another, just be as diligent as possible and don't go one way or another just because of laziness or negligence, instead be analyst if it's worth going one way or another based on your needs, and always take on count that not because you went that way this time it will be true for ALL your scenarios.

Hope it Helps!

Regards!

Comment: Perfect! :D I appreciate your view on the matter and will certainly remember it when the question arises again. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I use bundle when I want send data from fragment to fragment (from fragment to activity by interface, from activity to fragment by bundle).

If data is used in all fragments singleton is the best way, sometime I use also a istance of data objcet in activity that I manipulate in fragment by public methods of activity but I don't think that this is a best pratic.

Answer (score -1):

Please understand that 2 fragments can’t directly communicate with each other, They will need help of the activity under the context of which they are created. Using an interface :). 
Implement the interface in a fragment

interface `StartCommunication`

Define the interface in the activity whose context fragment is using

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    SendFragment.StartCommunication
```